# Confirmation page: Submit if GET variable set otherwise allow user to enter code

Tags: jquery, get

I have a simple html form for the user confirmation. Once the user registers they are sent a link to this page with a `GET` variable attached like this: `http://mysite/confirm?code=xyz123`

I am using the jquery validation plugin for all my form validations.

I have this validation code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#confirm').validate(
        {rules: {
            code: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 32,
                maxlength: 32
            }
        },

        messages: {
            code: {
                required: "Please enter the confirmation code",
                minlength: "Confirmation code is {0} characters",
                maxlength: "Confirmation code is {0} characters"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form){
            $.get("confirmnewuser.php",
                $('#code').val,
                function(data){
                    if(data.status == 0){
                        $('#message').append("<span class='error'>Error: " + data.message + "</span>");
                    }
                    else{
                        $('.container').hide();
                        $('.short_explanation').hide();
                        $('#message').append("<span>" + data.message + "</span>");
                    }
                },
            "json");
        }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I would like to test if the `GET['code']` variable **is set** which can be done easily like this:

`var $_GET = <?php echo json_encode($_GET); ?>;`

But at this point I don't know **where** to add this to my existing validation code and I don't know how to call the form submit handler (I'm fairly new to jquery/javascript).

Alternatively if the `GET` variable is not set then the page should load normally and the user can then enter their code in the input box.

**Edit: added Form Code**

```
    <form id='confirm' method='get' accept-charset='UTF-8'>

<div class='short_explanation'>* required fields</div>

<div id='message'></div>
<div class='container'>
    <label for='code' >Confirmation Code:* </label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='code' id='code' maxlength="32" /><br/>
</div>
<div class='container'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' id="submit" value='Confirm' />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: It seems that you are mixing up client side and server side validation, could you please edit your question by appending form code?

Comment: @ocanal: The client side validation would only be responsible for ensuring that a GET['code'] variable is set or if not then that the user entered a confirmation code. From the code I posted above this should be possible. I really only need to know how to add that $_GET code into my validation and to be able to call the submit handler for the form if that variable is set. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the situation is,

if user comes with this url-> `http://mysite/confirm`

The page will load normally, and user will enter its own code, then click the submit button.

But if user comes with this url-> `http://mysite/confirm?code=xyz123`

Form will load with defualt code "xyz12", and submit automatically.

If this is right than here is my solution,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var defaultCode = <?php echo json_encode($_GET); ?>;
    if (defaultCode != "") {
       $('#code').val(defaultCode); //set code
       $('#confirm').submit(); //submit form, so submitHandler will handle it
    }
});​
```

Comment: I figured it out and your code is what it looked like only I put it below the validation code. Works perfectly. I was going to put my own answer but you beat me to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code. I haven't tried it yet

```
submitHandler: function(form){
            if($('#code').val() == null || $('#code').val() == '')
                 return false;
            $.get("confirmnewuser.php",
                $('#code').val,
                function(data){
                    if(data.status == 0){
                        $('#message').append("<span class='error'>Error: " + data.message + "</span>");
                    }
                    else{
                        $('.container').hide();
                        $('.short_explanation').hide();
                        $('#message').append("<span>" + data.message + "</span>");
                    }
                },
            "json");
        }
```

And you dnt have to call submit separately, submit button should automatically do it.

Anyway you can invoke submit by using the code

```
$('#confirm').submit();
```